# Solve $x>\sqrt{1-x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, radicals

The solution to the above question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhG4O.jpg

In illustration 1.5, I can say that $x$ must be positive after plugging in negative values for $x$ and observing that the inequality isn't satisfied, but I do not understand how to logically conclude that $x$ must be positive. Is there an alternate way to prove that $x$ is positive other than experimentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**  $\sqrt{t} \geqslant 0$ by definition.

Comment: $\sqrt{t}>=0$ is true only when $\sqrt{t}$ is a function. How do you know my question is a function? Is every equation/inequality a function? If so, what is the domain and range of my function?

Comment: $\sqrt t$ is **defined** as the principal squared root, non negative. Read https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root. If you want any root use $\pm \sqrt t$ or $(t)^{½}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The $\sqrt{1-x}$ function always gives non-negative values. And $x$ is **strictly greater** than $\sqrt{1-x}$.

Comment: $\sqrt{1-x}$ doesn't have to be a function in the above question. It could just be an algebraic expression.

Comment: @viraj the expression is non negative, as I indicated seperately.  That's what the radical sign is intended to mean. For the answer my +1

Comment: ok cool I got it.